# Modbus TCP Client does not connect

Tags: pymodbus3, pymodbus

Background info:

I am trying to read data from my energy meter. I have connected a gprs modem to the meter(via rs485) port. This modem sends data via tcp-ip protocol to a specified server and port. On the server(aws ec2 instance) I can see a connection from the device.

Question:

When i try to connect to this device using PyModbus, i am unable to open connection.

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient as Modbusclient
client= Modbusclient(host=<internal ip of the connection>, port=5025)
if client.connect():
    print("Connected")
else:
    print("Not Connected")
```

The response is always "Not Connected".

I have ensured that a) the port is open. b) ip address is whitelisted on the server

Why can't i connect? What am i missing here?

Comment: Are you sure the port being used is correct?  Try reading a couple of registers and see what error it will throw.

Comment: The port was correct. I tried reading registers and got the same error i.e. client not connected. The problem was somewhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my particular case, the gprs modem was acting as a serial-over-tcp gateway.So i had to create a serial port and then connect to it. What i ended up doing was:

1. Create a pair of serial ports (e.g. p1 and p2) on Linux using socat command
2. Create a simple tcp listener (using sockets library in python)
3. Forward all data from tcp port to p1
4. Import ModbusSerialClient from pymodbus.client.sync
5. connect to P2 using Modbus Serial Client.